# Six questions for the story

Tags: story, situation

### 6 questions

1. A brick falls from an airplane carrying 1000 of the same over a forest. How many bricks fell to the ground?
2. How do you put a giraffe inside a fridge in three steps?
3. How do you put an elephant inside the fridge in four steps?
4. The lion king had called the animals to a party, but only one animal didn't attend. Which animal was it?
5. A hunter, somehow getting the information about the party, decides to kill the lion king and hence, decides to go to the party. But first, he has to go through a river infested with killer crocodiles. These killer crocodiles are very efficient with their job of guarding the secret party place, with a 100% kill rate. But the hunter manages to cross the river anyway. How?
6. The hunter finally arrives at the scene of the party. He retreats back to the river, thinking it would conceal his smell. He takes aim and decides to shoot, but something unexpected happens. He is dead the very next second. what happened?

After answering the questions above, make a story at the end with valid points from the answers you get.

**HINT**

> The answer to the first question isn't 1.

Comment: Can you quote a source for this puzzle? I've certainly seen #2-4 elsewhere on the web before, which makes me wonder about the others too... Thanks.

Comment: @Stiv As far as I know, this is a classic one.

Comment: I mean, I heard it from my friend... and then there are some additional questions #1, 5, 6... I doubt I can quote my friend here since he told me that physically :) (Also, I don't remember which friend asked me this particular set of questions...)

Comment: With chestnuts like this, it's quite common that there will be no way to provide meaningful attribution, so there's little sense in closing a question for that reason. (Unfortunately, chestnuts often are more *joke* than actual *riddle* and the "answer" is only "right" because "everyone" agrees what the "answer" is. Treated as an actual puzzle, they often allow good interpretations and answers that were not intended, making them poorly defined and/or invite—or even *require*—speculative or opinion-based answers, or ones which assume facts not given... and so end up closed anyway.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. A brick falls from an airplane carrying 1000 of the same over a forest. How many bricks fell to the ground?

> 0 bricks, the one that fell from the airplane didn't reach the ground.

> 2. How do you put a giraffe inside a fridge in three steps?

> You open the frige, put the giraffe inside and close the door.

> 3. How do you put an elephant inside the fridge in four steps?

> You open the fridge, take the giraffe out, put the elephant in and close the door.

> 4. The lion king had called the animals to a party, but only one animal didn't attend. Which animal was it?

> The elephant didn't come to the party as it was stuck in the fridge.

> 5. A hunter, somehow getting information about the party, decides to kill the lion king and hence, decides to go to the party. But first, he has to go through a river infested with killer crocodiles. These killer crocodiles are very efficient with their job of guarding the secret party place, with a 100% kill rate. But the hunter manages to cross the river anyway. How?

> All the crocodiles were at the party.

> The hunter finally arrives at the scene of the party. He retreats back to the river, thinking it would conceal his smell. He takes aim and decides to shoot, but something unexpected happens. He is dead the very next second. what happened?

> The hunter was hit in the head by a brick.

Comment: You funny, @Chengarda

Comment: Damn that was fast.

Comment: Yeah, this is a classic.